# What is the cause of "cannot get label for unreachable MBB" in llvm back-end?

Tags: llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I'm writing a llvm back-end, I'm meeting a problem for branch conditional instruction.

I want to translate the llvm IR branch to my specific target. below is what i have tried.

here is the llvm ir

```
  %6 = icmp slt i32 %4, %5
  br i1 %6, label %7, label %14
```

I have defined the instruction and instruction pattern, and i have write the compare instruction and pattern:

```
  def BNE: InstToy<4, (outs), (ins GPR32:$Rd,btargetS15:$S15), "bne\t$Rd, $S15", [(brcond GPR32:$Rd, bb:$S15)]> {
    bits<15> S15;
    bits<5>  Rd;  
    let Inst{19-5} = S15;
    let Inst{4-0} = Rd;
  }
```

The BNE instruction is check the Rd is zero, if no, it will jump to the target pc, otherwise do noting.
And i set "Legal" at isellowering

```cpp
  setOperationAction(ISD::BRCOND, MVT::i32, Legal);
```

but once i try the command compile the llvm ir

```sh
llc test.ll
```

it will raise the error:

```sh
llc: MachineBasicBlock.cpp:59: llvm::MCSymbol* llvm::MachineBasicBlock::getSymbol() const: Assertion `getNumber() >= 0 && "cannot get label for unreachable MBB"' failed.
```

I expect it can compiler without exception.

Answer (score 2):

with -print-after-all on in llc, i found out the MBB disappears after branch folding  pass, I found there is an error in analyzeBranch, after fixed that, the problem is fixed.